# CSS height:100% not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I want to achieve: When re-sized to mobile view the fly-out navigation should be 100% height, make the div "nav" 100% height of the page regardless of content inside the div "main".

I have tried setting the html, body to 100% height. The wrappers are also at 100% height, but it is not working.

here is my code sample:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GHJqh/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window ?

Comment: the other issue is when this line of code from #outer-wrap is removed, "overflow:hidden", the fly-out navigation then becomes scrollable, which on a phone should not be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `height:100%` to both the html and body for your solution to work. I've also applied it to the outer-wrap but I believe you may need a better solution as this would mess up a sticky footer if you are doing one.

**CODEPEN**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DAfoe/

Comment: notice when you try to add content to the page, the extra content is hidden on #outer-wrap. The problem is I want to scroll the content but the off-canvas nav should not be scrollable in the Y axis in mobile view - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xuHeD/

Comment: Hmm, Maybe you can try something similar to what I do on my site, Both elements sit inside the outer-container but the content div is a proxy window. Inspect the code at www.aktof.ca